# List images acting strange

Tags: 2010, site-template

I've created a custom site definition. According to some best practices, I kept it empty and deployed content with a couple of features. These features contain lists and libraries for instance, they're web scoped. The features are linked to the site definition so they are activated when the site is provisioned.

When I now create a new site collection based upon the definition, everything seems to work fine. But when I add a subsite based on the same definition to the root site, something strange happens. The "All Site Content" page isn't displaying any icons for libraries the features added to this site. I checked the HTML source, the image tag has no source i.e. src=""?

Furthermore it all seems to be working ok, but these kinds of things make me a bit nervous. So has anyone seen this behaviour before?

Answer (score 1):

Those icons are based on value of "Image" attribute of ListTemplate element. So  list instances created from same List Template would typically have save icons.

If you are using existing list templates to create your list instances, your list/library should have the same icons as out of the box list template icons. if you are creating lists from custom list templates, make sure you have Image attrubute specified in your ListTemplate Element.

Comment: I'm declaring a ListInstance in my feature, linked to a custom schema.xml. There's no custom template, just based on default document library template 101.

Comment: did you specify Type attribute of List element in your custom schema?